# Web app with multiple domains pointing to subfolders of a parent one

Tags: spring, tomcat, deployment, dns

I’m developing an application with Spring Boot, which runs under a domain, let’s say;

```
parentdomain.com
```

From one side the users enter their content, after logging in, at **parentdomain.com/admin**. This content is processed and made publicly accessible at a subfolder, let’s say;

```
parentdomain.com/user-one-content
parentdomain.com/user-two-content and so on.
```

**I need to point a domain for each user to his folder**, for example:

```
userone.com should be equivalent to parentdomain.com/user-one-content
```

The navigation should remain in the userone.com website.

userone.com/first-page should open parentdomain.com/user-one-content/first-page.

Right now the app is installed at PWS (Pivotal Web Services), but their routing system, doesn’t provide a solution to this approach, with multiple domains pointing to subfolders of a parent one.

**How could I archive this functionality?**

Answer (score 0):

I would leave Spring Boot alone and put in a web server in front of it.  Can you install Apache or Nginx?  Domain/sub-domain rerouting is out of the box in both of them.

Comment: The recommended web server is Tomcat, although it can be run on other ones, as far as they can handle Java Servlets. 

Maybe Apache or Nginx, could be combined with Tomcat. But it seems a much more complicated solution, than a service like PWS.

Comment: Then you should instead use HandlerInterceptor and on preHandle, you can change the domain and path based on your logic above.  For your app, it'll appear as if it came in on the right domain and path.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I could archive it, thanks to the advice from [gspatel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722283/gspatel)

With the rooting system of PWS, or other IaaS cloud provider I can root each domain to the whole application.

Implementing the preHandle method of a HandleInterceptor, I check whether the request is coming from my domain (`parentdomain.com` in the example). Or if it is coming from a domain of the sites, that the app is serving (`userone.com` in the example). In that case, I control that doesn't access  the parentdomain.com, or the content of other users, forwarding the request to the user home page (`user-one-content` in the example).

That's an extract, of my preHadle implementation:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

      ...

      String URI = request.getRequestURI();
      String rootURI = "/" + idweb + "/";

      if(URI.equals("/") || !URI.startsWith(rootURI)){ 
          URI = rootURI;

          RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath() + URI);
          requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

        }

    return true;
}
```