# Pointing a domain to a subfolder from another one with Amazon Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm developing an app with Spring Boot, which has to provide dynamic content to multiple domains. Each user will provide his content at the admin section of a parent site, let's say **parentsite.com**. Once processed, it will be accessible at **parentsite.com/user-number-one**, parentsite.com/user-number-two and so on.

**How could I manage to redirect the dynamic content of those subfolders, from the parent domain, to its own domain with Amazon Route 53?**

For example:

**parentsite.com/user-number-one** has to open **usernumberone.com**, keeping any further navigation in the user domain (usernumberone.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done with Route 53. Route 53 is a DNS server which resolves domain names to IP addresses. A DNS server does not see or process the protocol or path parts of a URL. The only part sent to a DNS server is the domain name.

You can do this via a number of methods on your web server. Create a new question for help on this.

Comment: Here I have set the question that @John Hanley suggests:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834691/web-app-with-multiple-domains-pointing-to-subfolders-of-a-parent-one/46837167?noredirect=1#comment80662895_46837167